# How can I define a unique URL for a user without using their ID?

Tags: javascript, php, url, hash, jsfiddle

Good evening guys, so I would like to know how jsfiddle.net does to save the content of the page in a unique url? For example: jsfiddle.net/u5jm5jq8. I was wondering how can I do this with javascript. Because you do not necessarily have to be logged in to save and be generated the unique url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a *hash ID*, a unique identifier typically generated from a unique attribute like an entity's primary key in the database. Hash IDs are usually shorter than typical hashes created by cryptographic hashing algorithms such as MD5 or SHA-256 and, unlike these, hash IDs are usually *reversible*, meaning we can decode the original value. They reduce exposure of your application's internal implementation which can improve security.

Check out [hashids.org](http://hashids.org/). This site provides implementations in various programming languages.

Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, avoid generating the hash IDs in the client. By creating the hash IDs on the server, you can guarantee that the IDs are unique and consistent with identifiers used by whatever mechanism your application stores data through.

**Edit for comment** - here's the procedure you might follow to use a hash ID in a URL:

Let's assume that we're using hash IDs to create links to user profiles. When we generate a page that contains a link to a profile, our application will:

1. Convert the user ID (ex. `5`) to a hash ID (ex. `3ac4jx60`)
2. Show the page with a link like `http://example.com/user/3ac4jx60`

If the site visitor clicks that link, the application will receive the request and:

3. Decode the hash ID in the URL to get the user ID (`3ac4jx60` → `5`)
4. Use the user ID to fetch the appropriate record and display the user's profile

Comment: Thank you. But how did the content of the page be saved in the url with that unique id? You could show the implementation of this with an example.

Comment: The content of the page is not encoded in the URL, only the value that identifies the data to show on the page. For example, when saving a JSFiddle, the site saves the code in the database with an ID, and then encodes that ID into a hash ID for public use. When the user visits the fiddle URL, the site decodes the hash ID back to the database ID. I updated my answer to illustrate this process.